# How to detect if Android Screen is dim ( going to off)

Tags: android, sdk, display

How can I check if displaying is in dim mode and will be off soon?
I want to disable touch in this mode and let the user just turn on the display and not draw on the screen.

In iOS, touches will not pass to the app while the screen is in dim mode, but in Android, they will and it's somehow annoying in paint-like apps.